# I'm using LaTeX2e book class (not memoir class). My publisher wants the final page of the index to have two columns of equal height. How do I do this?

Tags: two-column, indexing, books

There's nothing fancy in my preamble (just a few specially designed symbols, using \newcommand). I'm using the default Index provided in book class, so the Index has two columns on each page, except the final page. The code that was offered for memoir class does not work for me in book class.

Comment: You should mock up a sample document that replicates the current situation so we (the community) can work with something that helps your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use package `idxlayout` with option columns=2. This works for my book on Relativity with 3 columns index where I have this last page index:
[image]

```
\makeindex
\usepackage[columns=2]{idxlayout}
```

Comment: ...so, `columns=2` provides a 3-column layout?

Comment: No. \usepackage[columns=2]{idxlayout} produce 2 columns.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so very much, Raffaele.

Comment: @NeilTennant  Ok Neil. So You can accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro: So why do I see three columns? It's just not apparent that `columns=2` delivers 3 columns on the last page?

Comment: @Werner Sorry for my English not clear at all. In my book I have columns=3.